# Mousedown events and finding which cell the mouse was clicked down on

Tags: c#, winforms, mousedown, objectlistview, treelistview

I have a treelistview from objectlistview.

I would like to fire an event when the mouse is clicked down on a cell.

In particular I am not interested in editing the cell but firing an event and detecting which cell the mouse was clicked over so that I can get the value in that cell (from the treelistview model that I have created to display the information).

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why exactly was I down voted for this question? With out more clarity about the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure. I think there is someone who doesn't like the ObjectListView control and seems to down vote most OLV questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CellClick event you have your `CellClickEventArgs` which has the property `Item` item is the cell